# Transfer Skype history from Windows to Ubuntu

Tags: skype

Is there any way to transfer my history from my Windows Skype app to Skype in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but it should work.

First of all, exit from `skype`.

You need to copy Skype folder from your account on Windows(`C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Skype` on Windows7) to your Home folder on Linux(`/home/%USERNAME/`).

On your Home folder press `Ctrl+H` on file browser to see hidden files and folders. You should see folder with name `.Skype`. Make backup of it so you can restore it if something goes wrong. Than delete this folder and rename `Skype` folder to `.Skype`

Now try to run `skype`.

Answer (score 2):

Know this is a bit of an old question but, if you want to keep your logs in sync across both windows and linux, you can also accomplish this pretty easily if you use dropbox or a similar file sharing tool.

On your windows box:

You can follow this tutorial: http://lifehacker.com/5496652/how-to-use-symlinks-in-windows and make a symlink with your Skype username directory - making the target your dropbox/username directory and putting the link into the correct location to store user metadata for Skype on windows (it differs based on version - should be an easy google)

On your linux box:

Inside of your `.Skype` directory there should be a another directory named: `your_username`. You can back that directory up `mv your_username your_username_bu` and then create a symbolic link there pointing to your synced dropbox folder.

ex: `ln -s /home/<bob>/Dropbox/Logs/Skype/<skype_username> ./<skype_username>`

Now dropbox should keep your logs in sync at all times!